# How exactly works this async-await method call? is it correct?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular-promise

I am not so into Angular and async programming and I have the following doub.

Into a service class I have this async method:

```
  async aestheticEvaluationExist(patientUID: string) {
    console.log("patientUID: ", patientUID);
    //return this.firestore.collection('aestetic-evaluation').doc(patientUID).get();   

    //const docRef = (await this.firestore.collection('aestetic-evaluation').doc(patientUID).);
    const exists: boolean = (await this.firestore.collection('aesthetic-evaluation').doc(patientUID).get().toPromise()).exists;

    console.log("aesteticEvaluationExist() exists: ", exists);

    return exists;
  }
```

Then into my component class I have this method calling the previous service method::

```
let isUpdate = true;
(await this.patientService.aestheticEvaluationExist(this.patientUID)
                   .then(res => {
                                  console.log("RES: ", res);
                                  isUpdate = res;
                                }));

console.log("isUpdate: ", isUpdate);
```

As you can see it have **awayt** keyword before method call.

It seems to works fine (the output is correct) infact into the **then()** my res is false and when I print it by the last console.log() line it print **false**, it means that the original true value was correctly overwritten.

I am aksing if this **async** service method definition with the **await** keyword on the method call it ensure me that my last **console.log()** line is executed after that my method completed.

Is it my understanding correct? Or to ensure the correct result I have to perform this last operation inside the **then()**?

Comment: There is no reason to mix `await` and `then` in the same place. It *works* but it's needlessly complex. `let isUpdate = await this.patientService.aestheticEvaluationExist(this.patientUID)` does the same, it's shorter, and it's easier to read, understand, and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aksing if this async service method definition with the await keyword on the method call it ensure me that my last console.log() line is executed after that my method completed.

Yes, roughly. `async`/`await` is syntax for creating and consuming promises. An `async` function returns a promise. When code in the `async` function reaches the first `await`, the function returns its promise, waits for what the code used `await` on to settle, and then continues with the function logic, eventually settling the promise the `async` function returned.

So the logic of the function won't progress to that `console.log` until the promise you're `await`ing is settled.

---

Note that there's rarely a reason to combine explicit calls to promise methods like `then` and `catch` with `async`/`await` syntax. Use one or the other. (There's also no need to wrap the `await` operator and operand in `()`.) In this case, you can replace this:

```
let isUpdate = true;
(await this.patientService.aestheticEvaluationExist(this.patientUID)
    .then(res => {
        console.log("RES: ", res);
        isUpdate = res;
    }));
console.log("isUpdate: ", isUpdate);
```

with

```
let isUpdate = true;
const res = await this.patientService.aestheticEvaluationExist(this.patientUID);
console.log("RES: ", res);
isUpdate = res;
console.log("isUpdate: ", isUpdate);
```

or perhaps even

```
let isUpdate = await this.patientService.aestheticEvaluationExist(this.patientUID);
console.log("isUpdate: ", isUpdate);
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, and then follow on with coverage of `async`/`await` in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it my understanding correct?

No, you do not combine `async` / `await` with the `.then()` syntax as they are both trying to achieve the same job.

The following are equivelant.

```
const myResult = await this.someAsyncFunction();
console.log(myResult);
```

and

```
this.someAsyncFunction().then(myResult => {console.log(myResult);});
```

So in your example you'd want to do the following

```
const isUpdate = await this.patientService.aestheticEvaluationExist(this.patientUID)
console.log("isUpdate: ", isUpdate);
```