# Getting and storing a global variable

Tags: angular

I am struggling with a simple concept I can easily do in C#, but not in Angular.

I am trying to store the user profile in a service I add in every component, so I do not get the profile every time a component is loaded/displayed.

So, I created a service, where the constructor gets the user profile, and saves it in a variable, and use a getter for all my components.

The issue I have, is that when the components call the getter, the variable is net set yet, as the service has not responded yet. This leads to an undefined error and breaks the component as the profile is vital in the code of the component.

In C#, I would simply put 1 await when getting the profile, so that everything else can run without waiting, as I know the data is there.

But in Angular, I tried that, but it does not seem to work.

```
export class SharedService {
  private userProfile;
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    this.initProfile();
  }
  async initProfile(): Promise < void > {   
    this.userProfile =await this.http.getProfile().subscribe((data: any) => {
       //...
    }
  });

  getUserProfile() {
    return this.userProfile;
  }
}
```

The getprofile:

```
  getProfile() {
    return this.shttp.get(environment.apiEndpoint + 'Getprofile/', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: '*/*'
      })
    });
  }
```

In the components, when I call my getUserProfile function, the service answers immediately with the empty userProfile.

EDIT:
I manage to have the desired behavior, with very nasty code snippet, but this should make clear what I am trying to accomplish. In my profile.component.ts:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void>  {    
 while (this.profile == null) {
  await this.sharedService.sleep(500);
  this.profile = this.sharedService.getUserProfile();    
 }
 if (this.profile.isadmin){
  this.CalculateStuff();
 }
 //
 //imagine here even more code using the this.profile variable in if statements, 
 //cases, etc.
 //
}
```

The sleep function

```
  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

The fact I have to code a sleep function to achieve this, is a clear signal to me that i am doing something wrong. That is why I am here.

Comment: if you like to work with promises, convert observable to promise: `this.userProfile =await this.http.getProfile().toPromise()`; should be better

Comment: You can't `await` a subscription or observable and get the resulting value, that only works with promises. You can use `.toPromise` as @Andrei suggests, or lean into RxJS (so much of Angular is based around observables, I'd suggest the latter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You're awaiting a subscription which doesn't work with `async` / `await`. Just do the following. Just convert it to a promise so you can `await` it.

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void>  {  
  this.profile = await this.sharedService.getUserProfile().toPromise();    
 if (this.profile.isadmin){
  this.CalculateStuff();
 }
}
```

This question is similar [How exactly works this async-await method call? is it correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171247/how-exactly-works-this-async-await-method-call-is-it-correct/66171334#66171334)

To give you a bit more detail. What you're doing is assigning `this.userProfile` to the RXJS subscription object. This will not give you the value that you need. If you want to stay with Rxjs as suggested in one of the comments. You can just do all the logic for the user profile inside the subscribe block.

```
  this.http.getProfile().subscribe((userProfile: any) => {
       // do userProfile actions here
  });
  //Since subscribe is an async callback, anything outside that block will have userProfile undefined.
```

Also as mentioned, a rudimentary knowledge of RxJs will be very useful and solve a lot of your early issues. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I am trying to avoid to have to put all my code in the subscribe answer. As mentioned earlier, a lot of code depends on the profile's content, so, before posting this, it is what I was doing.

Isn't it possible to simply stop the flow of code execution as long as the userprofile is not set in the service? Since everything else depends on it. Or am I missing something? How can you work with a promise, if you need the values to make decisions in the code?

Comment: Yes that is possible with the first block of code in my answer (it is possible with subscriptions too but a little more complicated). When you convert an observable to a promise and `await` it. Your function waits until the promise completes (either successfully or by throwing an error). the promise will complete and then you can use `this.userProfile` like a "normal" variable in the lines below.

Comment: I am sorry, yes, you are right, that code block is stopping. My question was badly formulated. What I meant is, my components do not seem to wait for the code to be done executing. It will get the undefined/unset user profile from the shared service, even if the shared service is still "waiting" on the getprofile from the http service.

Comment: Ahh yes. This is a fundamental part of async code in Angular. You need to null check in the template using `ngIf="userProfile"` (the this isn't needed) in order to not try and do anything with the null value. When the profile promise completes, the value will no longer be null and the template will perform an update for the new "non-null" profile. Could you provide a code example of what exactly is causing an issue?

Comment: I allready do the ngIf in the templates, works wonders :)
The issue is in the code files. Here is an example of in my code file, I need the content of the userProfile to set the account value:
  " this.account = this.userProfile.account;". Since the userProfile is not set, it gives an error.

Now, I can see that I could avoid this, by also using a global variable for the account,  and do it in the shared service. But I fear at some point, the issue will be the same, I need those values for some checks in my code?

Comment: Well in this case you'd just make the assignment after `this.userProfile = await this.http.getProfile().toPromise();` since your userProfile is defined. Without actually seeing the code. It is difficult to know what you're attempting.

Comment: Too bad we cannot start a chat, it seems I do not have the REP for it :( So, hard to explain without clear code indeed. You have the code of sharedservice. Now, imagine, i have a "profile" component, in where i do the following in the ngOnInit : this.profile = this.sharedservice.getusrprofile(); if (this.profile.isadmin==true) calculateTotalInvoices();. As soon as I will try to do that, this will get an error, as profile.isadmin is still undefined at this point in time. That is why i try to stop everything, as long as the profile data is not filled in.

Comment: "So, hard to explain without clear code indeed." You can add code to your question by editing it. That would really help. My TLDR answer would be to make your userProfile an observable itself and then you can subscribe to it in your child components similar to what @Michael D suggested. Without it, it's almost impossible to give an answer that would be useful to you

Comment: That... was also an option! I added more code. I hope its a bit more clear what I am trying to do, and why. And yes, I know my edit is absolutely not the answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the thing you're trying to achieve (top code snippet). Everything inside the `ngOninit()` will wait for that `await`

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code and made some changes, this works perfectly now. However, I fear this is not the right way to do it., because of all the hassle. Should this have been done using RXJS?

Comment: This is a perfectly fine way of doing things. It is simple and clear. If you need to achieve certain things then using variables as observables themselves is a good strategy (too much to go into in a comment). Other people in this thread have suggested learning resources. I'd recommend that. Also most tutorial Angular courses will include some sort of observables.

Comment: Ok. Once again, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

One other way would be to make the `userProfile` in the service a multicast observable (like RxJS `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1). That way there isn't a need to mix observables with promises.

**Service**

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

export class SharedService {
  private userProfile = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    this.initProfile();
  }

  initProfile() {   
    this.http.getProfile().subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.userProfile.next(data);           // <-- push the new profile
      },
      error: (error: any) => { }               // <-- handle error
  });

  getUserProfile(): Observable<any> {          // <-- return observable here
    return this.userProfile.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Now in the component you could subscribe to the subject from the service. Additionally you could use `takeUntil` operator with `Subject` to close the open subscription when the component is closed/destroyed.

**Component**

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public userProfile: any;
  private closed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private shared: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shared.getUserProfile().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.closed$)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.userProfile = data;
        // other statements that depend on `this.userProfile`
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();   // <-- close open subscription(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: I definitely need to put some (a lot?) of time in rxjs, this sounds like a foreign language to me :( But thank you for writing this out. I will come back to it when I have a better grasp of rxjs. Hopefully, soon!

Comment: @Hedi: While the [RxJS docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) could provide valuable reference, I wouldn't recommend it as a starting point. They are blunt information designed to supplement existing knowledge. Instead you could start using [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/). They provide more context to each functions and operators and provide easy to grasp examples. You could also use [rxmarbles.com](https://rxmarbles.com/) to supplement LearnRxJS.

Comment: thanks again for the info. I will bookmark your comment and come back to it when starting RXJS!